# Gradle run task only on defined property

Tags: if-statement, gradle, groovy, conditional-statements, gradlew

I am struggling to let a task only execute when a specific value is defined.

I'm using Gradle 3.5.

```
task signJar(type: SignJar, dependsOn: reobfJar) {
    onlyIf {
        project.hasProperty('mod_keystore')
    }

    keyStore = project.keyStore
    alias = project.keyStoreAlias
    storePass = project.keyStorePass
    keyPass = project.keyStoreKeyPass
    inputFile = jar.archivePath
    outputFile = jar.archivePath
}
```

As you can see, I already tried the onlyIf statement, but the task still runs. This results into a crash:

```
Could not get unknown property 'keyStore' for root project 'JustAnotherEnergy' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

The property '*mod_keystore*' is no where defined, but the code get's executed.

```
task signJar(type: SignJar, dependsOn: reobfJar) {
    if(project.hasProperty('mod_keystore')) {
        keyStore = project.keyStore
        alias = project.keyStoreAlias
        storePass = project.keyStorePass
        keyPass = project.keyStoreKeyPass
        inputFile = jar.archivePath
        outputFile = jar.archivePath
    }
}
```

This works. The code does not get executed, but I'm running into other problems:
If the property '*mod_keystore*' is not defined, Gradle can't set a value for the for example '*keyStore*' property, but the task SignJar requires this values to be set.

This means this task should only be executed when the property '*mod_keystore*' is defined. If it is not defined, the task should be skipped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> As you can see, I already tried the onlyIf statement, but the task still runs.

No, the task does not run. You need to distinguish between the *configuration phase* and the *execution phase*. The task closure, where you are setting your task properties, is executed during the *configuration phase*, right after the task is created. Only task actions (defined by the task type) and closures added via `doFirst` or `doLast` are executed during the *execution phase*.

If you disable or skip a task via `onlyIf` or `enabled`, you only disable / skip the *execution (phase)* of the task, not its *configuration (phase)*.

As a solution for your specific problem, you can rely on your first approach with the `onlyIf` condition, but add a fail-safe way to access your project properties:

```
task signJar(type: SignJar, dependsOn: reobfJar) {
    onlyIf {
        hasProperty('mod_keystore')
    }

    keyStore = findProperty('keyStore')
    alias = findProperty('keyStoreAlias')
    storePass = findProperty('keyStorePass')
    keyPass = findProperty('keyStoreKeyPass')
    inputFile = jar.archivePath
    outputFile = jar.archivePath
}
```